# GraphQL Apollo types generation on React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, neo4j, graphql, apollo

I'm using

- Neo4J 4.2
- Apollo server
- GraphQL & @neo4j/graphql (to generate Neo4J types from `schema.graphql`)
- Expo React Native + Apollo Client
- TypeScript

And I wanted to generate TS types for GraphQL queries by following [this tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/tooling/apollo-codegen/typescript-graphql-code-generator-generate-graphql-types/).

[By default apollo-cli](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/devtools/apollo-config/#clientincludes) will look in `./src` folder, but in React Native I don't have such a folder, it's all in root. So when I tried to change `includes` config for apollo client like so:

```
<root>/apollo.config.js

module.exports = {
  client: {
    includes: ['**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
  },
};
```

Running

```
> apollo codegen:generate --endpoint=http://localhost:4001/ --target=typescript --tagName=gql
```

Resulted in:

```
Error: Error initializing Apollo GraphQL project "Unnamed Project": Error: Error in "Loading queries for Unnamed Project": Error: ️️There are multiple definitions for the `OpName` operation. Please rename or remove all operations with the duplicated name before continuing.
```

Answer (score 1):

After many hours, I fixed this issue by using the following config:

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    includes: ['graphql/**/*.ts'],
  },
};
```

My guess is that apollo-cli found some `gql` tags in all the React Native generated code.

P.S. I tried to use specific keywords so that Google will show this result to people that have the same issue and are stuck.